# how to redirect the user to another view after filling in a django form?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I created a form from django, and I would redirect the user to another page of my application (another url) once the user has filled out the form.
The form is in the 'data/celiac' url ('celiac.html'), and I would like to redirect it to the 'data/cdr3' url. After writing the following code, when the user completes the form, he is redirected to the same url 'data/celiac'. What should I change in my code in order to be redirected to the 'data/cdr3' url please?
CeliacViews:

```
def CeliacView(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = forms.CeliacForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        columns = form.cleaned_data['columns']
        algo = form.cleaned_data['algo']
        context = {'form': forms.Cdr3Form()}
        return render(request, 'data/cdr3.html', context)
else:
    tableData = get_table_data_to_representation()
    context = {'form': forms.CeliacForm(), 'tableData': tableData}
    return render(request, 'data/celiac.html', context)
```

Cdr3Views:

```
def Cdr3View(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    my_form = forms.Cdr3Form(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if my_form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        kmers = my_form.cleaned_data['kmers']
        threshold = my_form.cleaned_data['threshold']
        learning_rate = my_form.cleaned_data['learning_rate']
        epochs = my_form.cleaned_data['epochs']
        split = my_form.cleaned_data['split']

        # TODO: Call data and run machine learning model
        x_dataset, y_dataset = get_dataset_celiac(int(kmers))
        train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = split_data(int(split), x_dataset, y_dataset)
        parameters, v, m = initialization_of_parameters(int(kmers))
        train_results = train(parameters, v, m, epochs, learning_rate, threshold, train_x, train_y)
        data_for_report = test(test_x, test_y, threshold, train_results)
        fig = presentation_of_results(data_for_report)
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(buf, format='PNG', bbox_inches='tight')
        buf.seek(0)
        string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
        image = parse.quote(string)
        return render(request, 'data/cdr3Results.html', {'data': image})

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    context = {'form': forms.Cdr3Form()}
    return render(request, 'data/cdr3.html', context)
```

And urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'data'
urlpatterns = [
   path('datasets/', views.SetView, name='datasets'),
   path('celiac/', views.CeliacView, name='celiac'),
   path('cdr3/', views.Cdr3View, name='cdr3'),
   path('cdr3results/', views.Cdr3Results, name='cdr3Results')
   ]
```

my template celiac.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: If you reidrect the context and the form will be "lost".

Comment: You can specify in you `celiac.html` template `<form action="{% url 'cdr3' %}" method="post">` to post to a different url.

Comment: i don't want to redirect from my template (because my input form is "submit"), but as you can see in my CeliacViews.py, after retrieving the form data from my view (in if request.method == 'POST' :), I return "return render (request, 'data / cdr3.html', context)".  But the problem is that the url after the submit is 'data/celiac' and not 'data/cdr3'

Comment: But a template is not in any way related to a view. A template is just a file that you can use to generate content. But a view can render zero, one, or multiple templates. The fact that the template "happens" to be rendered by `data/cdr3` does not matter. The fact that it shares the same name does not matter either.

Comment: return redirect('cdr3') instead of return statement inside if block

Comment: thank for your help @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SahilDesai it was the good one